# Apache SHTML including a PHP file

Tags: apache-2.2, php, server-side-includes

Following this question

[HTAccess Directory Index with PHP-Files](https://serverfault.com/questions/186363/htaccess-directory-index-with-php-files)

I was able to create my index using a PHP file included in a SHTML file as follows

```
<!--#include virtual="/header.php" -->
```

This is written in the "header.shtml" which is declared as `HeaderName` in the `.htaccess`-file.

Now, this works perfectly fine on my local host (a MAMP-PRO), but when I upload it to my webspace, it won't work - The file is not included. When I check the source code, the directive written above to include the PHP is just written in plain text, so it seems it's not executed by the server.

Is there a flag I need to set to make this work? Or any workaround?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hoster must load mod_include. Also, someone (the hoster or you) has to configure it:

```
AddType text/html .shtml
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
```

Also, either in .htaccess or in the < Directory > block matching your directory:

```
Options +Includes
```

Comment: I had those already in my `.htaccess`

Comment: Does shtml work for including HTML files, without PHP in the game?

Answer (score 1):

SSI probably needs to be [enabled](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_include.html#enabling).

Comment: I asked my provider and he assures me that it is enabled.